# Windows: Throw new mongoose.Error.MissingSchemaError(name);

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

Mongod is running normally in windows terminal but Nodemon showing the following errors:

```
C:\Users\enzoc\desktop\api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:520
      throw new mongoose.Error.MissingSchemaError(name);
      ^

MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Usuario".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
    at Mongoose.model (C:\Users\enzoc\desktop\api\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:520:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\enzoc\desktop\api\controllers\UsuarioController.js:2:26)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:973:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:997:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\enzoc\desktop\api\routes\api\v1\usuario.js:3:27)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1108:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1137:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:973:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:813:14)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:997:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:92:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\enzoc\desktop\api\routes\api\v1\index.js:3:25)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Here I will put some pictures of the files that give the error
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IOpU1.jpg
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/40s00.jpg
[3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UOFo.jpg
[4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7TikF.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You have either not defined a schema for usario or you have not imported it to be used in .model() function.
You can try something similar to this

```
const Usario = mongoose.model('User', new Schema({ name: String }));
```

For further examples and function documentation, you can go to https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/model.html#model_Model or https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/schema.html#schema_Schema

Comment: thanks, I created this schema it is in UsuarioController, I don't know why he is not finding it

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we are stuck with this kind of problem always remember to check the stack-trace!

```
> at Object.<anonymous>
> (C:\Users\enzoc\desktop\api\controllers\UsuarioController.js:2:26)
```

If you check this line, U will understand that in ***UsuarioController*** line number *2*,   ***Usuario Model/Schema***  has been initialized. But there is no file in your system with te respected name. Please create that file.

For more details check  [to create a mongoose schema](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html).

Hope your problems resolved!